# A shell script question about Apostrophe and Quotation Mark

Tags: shell

I writing a script that adds alias in .bashrc automatically.

I have to write `alias A='source /MY_HOME_DIR/a.sh'` in the .bashrc.

So my script was `echo "alias A=/'source ${HOME}/a.sh\'" >> ~/.bashrc` but It's not working.

Any idea? thank you in advance.

Comment: I think it is because of $ sign before {HOME}.

Comment: Don't use aliases. `A() { source "$HOME"/a.sh "$@"; }` doesn't require you to add all the extra single quotes and backslashes at all in the first place, and you can append it to bashrc with `declare -F A >>~/.bashrc` -- still no single quotes or backslashes needed.

Comment: sry for my mistyping I have revised it to ${HOME}

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "alias A='source ${HOME}/a.sh'"
```

is working well.

It's interesting. I though `${HOME}` won't work between `''`.

Comment: `${HOME}` does not work in singly-quoted strings, but it is expanded when calling echo, because then it belongs to a doubly-quoted string.

Answer (score -1):

It is because you miss $ sign before {HOME}.

Comment: That's _a_ problem, but it's not the _only_ problem; the OP's code still doesn't work with it fixed.

Comment: sry for my mistyping I have revised it to ${HOME}